# Application expected to run in background on interval crashes without LOGCAT after 500-1000 iterations

Tags: java, android

My application is expected to be run once by the user and the background process will run indefinitely as the app runs. The background process is supposed to run a handler (I use badoo WeakHandler) on 5s interval.
However, after 500 - 1000 iterations of the interval, the application would terminate itself without any notification on the logcat **(I will provide the screenshot later)**. I set my logcat to `Verbose` and `No Filter`.

How can I make sure that the application can run reliably without crashing?

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.badoo.mobile:android-weak-handler:1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

My application only has one activity, which is `MainActivity.java`.
Here is my Runnable

```
    private Runnable captureInterval = new Runnable() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                File f = new File(videoPath);
                try {
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    f.delete();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    mMediaRecorder.release();
                    mMediaRecorder = null;
                }
            }
            if (mVirtualDisplay != null) {
                mVirtualDisplay.release();
                mVirtualDisplay = null;
            }
            if (!mKeyguardManager.isKeyguardLocked()) {
                initRecorder();
                shareScreen();
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
```

Comment: we can't guess the exception. please provide the actual exception.